# Data Warehouse - unique constraint on dimension tables, is such design possible?

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

The database used is postgresql.

Suppose I have dimension table `dim_orders` with fields describing order line (one order number can has many order line, different on item name):

- `order_id` (auto-increment primary key)
- `order_number`
- `order_status` (NEW, PAID, ORDERED, ...)
- `item_name`
- ...

Then I have ETL process that runs hourly. The data source is from sales database. The problem is, we have `order_line_status` field, which can change hour-to-hour (e.g. one cycle will be `NEW > PAID > ORDERED > DELIVERED > CLOSED`) on the data source. And this order status can be different for each order. For example, when order X has line X1 (item : chocolate) and line X2 (item : coffee), the X1 chocolate might already DELIVERED, but X2 coffee still on ORDERED.

My `fact_sales` table is something like this:

- `sales_id` (auto-increment primary key)
- `order_id` (foreign key to `dim_orders`), which basically the order line : chocolate or coffee on sample above
- `quantity` (taken from sales data)
- `discount_amount` (taken from sales data)
- ...

To maintain speed, I'd like to avoid network / SQL call everytime the ETL process runs.
This is because the network sometimes full and quite slow.

Right now, every ETL process one sales data, I query from `dim_orders` :

```
    **existing_order_id = "SELECT order_id FROM dim_orders WHERE order_number = [staging_data.order_number] AND item_name = [staging_data.item_name]"**

    if existing_order_id found then:
        - update dim_orders set order_status = new order status from staging data (it might changed or not since last hour ETL)
        - update fact_sales, using data on staging table
    else:
        - insert into dim_sales, get new order_id. Something like (INSERT INTO dim_orders ... RETURNING order_id)
        - insert into fact_sales, using order_id
```

The problem is on the bold statement, where I always query for existing order ID. If I have 10k rows, this means 10k select before processing the data. I'm trying to change the `dim_orders`, using unique key on (`order_number, item_name`), so instead of select-insert/update, I can have something like this (I think)

```
    A. upsert data from staging_table into dim_orders. If existing (order_number, item_name) match, update the order_status.

    B. process the fact table, using returned order id
```

Since we can get the order id from fact table, query A can be achieved by:

```sql
INSERT INTO dim_orders (order_number, item_name, order_status, ...) VALUES (...) 
    ON CONFLICT(order_number, item_name) DO UPDATE 
    SET order_status = excluded.order_status
    RETURNING order_id
```

Now, the only problem to do this, I have to add unique constraint on `dim_orders` where `(order_number, item_name)` must be unique.
However, this design is rejected, because we never have unique constraint on dimension tables before. But from what I get, the reason is because we never done it before.

So my question is:

- is it OK to add unique constraint on star schema (fact / dim tables)? Or it is actually bad by design, why?
- In term of data warehouse, is there any other approach for this kind of select-insert/update problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely add unique constraints where possible. This can assist the query optimiser to pick a fast query plan, and enforces data integrity.

Comment: I read through the description of your upserts process and it _seems_ like you ar edoing a row by row upsert. That is definitely bad practice. The alternaitve approach you described - a set based upsert from a staging table - is far better

Comment: You should always have an index on the business key of a dimension otherwise, as you’ve discovered, processing of that dimension doesn’t perform with dimensions of any reasonable size. Whether that index can be a unique constraint or not depends on the type of SCD you are using